# Converting rpm to deb error execution (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation

When I am trying to convert `rpm` files to `deb` files this error executes and I can't understand the problem

```
LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{NAME} 'adlmapps11-11.0.15-0.x86_64.rpm'
sh: 1: rpm: not found
Error executing "LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{NAME} 'adlmapps11-11.0.15-0.x86_64.rpm'":  at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 489.
```

and here is the command that I used

```
sudo alien -cv *.rpm
```

anyone can help please?

Comment: Are you running the command in the folder where the ROMs are supposed to be?

Comment: I am running the command where the rpm files exist in a folder in the home directory

Comment: @dessert when I remove  sudo it tells me
    Must run as root to convert to deb format (or you may use fakeroot).

Comment: Could you please [edit] and provide a link where one can download the `.rpm` file?

Comment: @dessert it is the download files of Autodesk Maya , I extracted the tar file and then tried to convert the rpm files to deb, It worked for the first time but I deleted them cause an error occurred, and then it won't convert them again

Comment: Where did you get that `.tar` file? Please [edit] and provide the link!

Comment: @HassanSaeed completely same problem, it worked in the first time, then it crashed. did solve it and if so how did? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved completely the same error with

```
sudo apt install rpm --reinstall
```